# How to bind extra props to component rendered by v-for?

Tags: vue.js, components, v-for

This is a newbie question but I cannot find answer/hint online:

For a basic template that is rendered by a v-for loop:

```html
<div id="app">
    <ul class="list">
        <v-ml_component v-for="data_item in get_data.Value" 
                        v-bind:item="data_item" 
                        v-bind:index="data_index" 
                        v-bind:key="data_item.id" 
                        v-bind:messageType="messageType">
        </v-ml_component>
    </ul>
</div>

<template id="list-template">
    <li>
        <span v-if="messageType.indexOf('inbox') >= 0">{{ item.MessageId }}</span>
        <span>{{index}}</span> : {{ item.Subject }}
    </li>
</template>
```

Everything is straight forward as in basic example, except I need to pass a prop to this component:

```js
$.getJSON(mockAjaxUrl).done(function(ajaxdata){
    var messageType = 'inbox';
    Vue.component('v-ml_component', {
        template:'#list-template',
        props:['index', 'item', 'messageType']
    });

    var vm = new Vue({
        el:"#app",
        data:{
            messageType: messageType,
            get_data: ajaxdata
        }
    });
});
```

This would get error in console that messageType is not passed to this component. I wonder how the value of this property can be passed to a template that is rendered with a v-for loop?

Answer (score 3):

The `messageType` prop will be `message-type` in HTML.

See [camelCase vs. kebab-case](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#camelCase-vs-kebab-case) in the Vue docs.

Comment: Thanks! This works. It seems Vue.js forces naming rule to be hyphen connection when it meets Uppercase letter. To avoid this trouble, you can use names like whateveritmaybe.